# Записать данные с get запроса в объект. Express, JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Пытаюсь записать то, что получил с get запроса в объект, но записываются только последняя пара ключ-значение.
После чего решил создать массив объектов, но ситуация такая же.
Я понимаю почему так происходит - значение перезаписываются с каждой итерацией цикла, но как быть?

```
let offset = new Date().toISOString();
let url = 'http://public.api.openprocurement.org/api/2.4/tenders?offset=' + offset + '+02.00';

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    request.get(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        body = JSON.parse(body);

        var tendersList = [];
//начало
         body.data.forEach(function (item) {
        tendersList[item.id] = [];
        tendersList[item.id].push(item.dateModified);
    });
//конец

        console.log(tendersList);

        res.render('index', {tenders: body});
    });
});
```

Comment: вы в фориче каждый раз перезаписываете переменную `tendersList `, используйте `tendersList.push({...})`  чтобы добавлять элементы в массив

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, в таком случае у меня не будет пары ключ-значение..или я неправильно снова делаю?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych я изменил код

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, сделал. Изменил в коде

Comment: если вам нужно "ключ-значение" то используйте вместо массива обычный обьект

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych вот не получается почему-то..не могли бы подсказать?

Comment: сейчас накидаю коротенький примерчик

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, просто я потом хочу сохранить этот объект в MongoDB. собственно поэтому и думал что лучше делать массив объектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с обьектом :

```js
var data = [{ dateModified: 'a1', id: 1 },
            { dateModified: 'a2', id: 2 },
            { dateModified: 'a3', id: 3 }];
            
var tendersList = {};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  // у обьекта tendersList создаем свойство с именем item.id (наш ключ)
  // и присваиваем ему значение item.dateModified
  tendersList[item.id] = item.dateModified;
});

console.log(tendersList);

// пример перебора свойств обьекта tendersList :
Object.keys(tendersList).forEach(e => {
  console.log(tendersList[e]);
});
```

Пример с массивом обьектов :

```js
var data = [{ dateModified: 'a1', id: 1 },
            { dateModified: 'a2', id: 2 },
            { dateModified: 'a3', id: 3 }];
            
var tendersList = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  tendersList.push({
    id : item.id,
    value : item.dateModified
  });
});

console.log(tendersList);
```